# Instagram upload video from pc

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, instagram

I'm trying to automate the process of uploading videos/images on instagram (without using a private API). For now i automated the image uploading and i'm trying to do the same thing for the videos. I'm doing this with `electron` and `Nodejs`.

for click the upload button and select an image I execute this code that actually works fine.

```
const fs = require('fs'),
      {remote} = require('electron'),
      clipboardy    = require('clipboardy'),
      BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;

const LOAD_IMAGE = '.UP43G',
      NEW_POST = '.glyphsSpriteNew_post__outline__24__grey_9.u-__7';

function get_files(path){
    return fs.readdirSync(path, { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter(dirent => dirent.isFile())
    .map(dirent => __dirname + '/../../' + path + '/' + dirent.name);
}

function randomRange(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function createWindow (session_id, hidden) {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    });
    win.loadURL('https://www.instagram.com');
    return win;
}

////select the files to upload////

var files = UPLOAD_POST_FOLDER_CUSTOM
var file_to_upload = files[randomRange(0, files.length - 1)];

///////////////////////////////////////

function async upload_image(){
    // click the upload button on the page
    await electron_window.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
        async function click_upload_button(){
            let new_post_button = document.querySelector('${NEW_POST}');
            await sleep(1000);
            new_post_button.click()
        }
        click_upload_button();
    `);
    // write the path of the file and press enter in the file selector
    await sleep(500);
    let previous_clipboard = clipboardy.readSync();
    clipboardy.writeSync(file_to_upload);
    await fake_input.keyTap('l', 'control');
    await fake_input.keyTap('v', 'control');
    await fake_input.keyTap('enter');
    clipboardy.writeSync(previous_clipboard);       
    await sleep(2000);

}
```

This code works fine for images `.jpg`. The problem that i'm facing is that during the uploading, when it opens the file selector for choose something to post **it doesn't recognize the videos**. I tried all the possible video extensions.

I also tried to write the file path in the file selector instead select it manually  and I saw that if u write a non `.jpg`/`.mp4` file it show a warning *only images are allowed*, instead, if you write the path to a `.jpg` file it uploads the image and if you write a file to `.mp4` it closes the file manager and do nothing, like that it ignores that you are trying to upload something.

**To reproduce**

- go to instagram
- do the login
- click `F12` for open the dev tools
- click `CTRL + SHIFT + M` for toggle the device emulation
- select any device or resize the page for toggle the mobile view of the site
- reload the site
- try to upload something by clicking the bottom `+` button.

(The video is 6mb (< 15mb that is the maximum) and 40seconds (<60s that is the maximum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [instagram private api client](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api) will do better job than your approach

Comment: I want to work with the browser directly and not make with request modules or somethin like this also because each time that you log in from the private api it sends a mail that say a new access has been  done ecc.. and that's a bit boring

Comment: You can store session data, reuse it and not receive emails that login was performed. Here's the example https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api/blob/master/examples/session.example.ts

Comment: Also, your current approach relies on css selectors containing hashes and I'm 100% sure they change from time to time and you'll be much more bored updating these selectors

Comment: can it interact with the two factory authentication too?

Comment: Yes, it can https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api/blob/master/examples/2fa-sms-login.example.ts

Answer (score 1):

If you want to publish a video via the API, you have to do the following two steps:

- create a media object container by using the `POST /{ig-user-id}/media` endpoint
- publish the container with `POST /{ig-user-id}/media_publish`

Example Request:

```
POST graph.facebook.com/89751400008469714/media
  ?media_type=VIDEO
  &video_url=https//www.example.com/videos/my-video.mov
  &caption=#myfirstvideo!
```

Try using a **.mov** file. If this doesn´t fix the problem, you can check if your video has the following characteristics:

- 3,500 kbps video bitrate
- H.264 codec / MP4 format
- 3 to 60 seconds duration
- maximum width 1080 pixels (1080P)
- 29.96 frames per second
- AAC audio codec at 44.1 kHz mono

Comment: The Example Request will return the ID (e.g. 012345) of the container. Then you will have to publish this ID with the following code sample:

POST graph.facebook.com/89751400008469714/media_publish
  ?creation_id=012345

Comment: How do I format the video to meet these requirements?